# How to run mocha tests synchronously, for POST and GET request

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, couchbase, chai

I built an API for a couchbase database, and I am currently working on writing tests with mocha for my HTTP requests. The issues which I am running into, is that my GET request test cannot find the data which was added with the POST request test. If the database has data stored in it before the tests are run, the GET request test will pass. But the data which it returns does not include the newly added data from the POST request test. I need to be able to run the tests on a clean database and have all the tests pass. I believe that the issue is being caused due to mocha's asynchronous nature, but I'm not really sure how to fix this. Here's my test cases.

**Dependencies**

```
const expect = require('chai').expect;
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../src/app');
```

**POST request test**

```
describe(`POST requests`, ()=>{
  it('Add new data', function() {
    return request(app)
      .post('/someendpoint')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', auth_token)
      .send(newData)
      .expect(200)
      .then( function(res) {
        expect(res.body).be.a('Object');
        expect(res.body.id).be.a('string');
        id = res.body.id;
      })
    });
  });
```

**GET request test**

```
describe('GET requests', function() {
  it('Get data', function() {
    return request(app)
      .get('/someendpoint')
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')
      .set('Authorization', auth_token)
      .expect(200)
      .then((res) => {
        expect(res.body).be.a('Array');
      })
    });
  });
```

Also, if it make a difference. Every time a POST request is made, a new document is created in the couchbase database

**Here's a poor solution that I found (Edit)**

```
    before('timer for get data', function(){
        for(let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
        }
    })
    
    it('get data', function() {
        return request(app)
        .get('/someendpoint')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('Authorization', auth_token)
        .expect(200)
        .then((res) => {
            expect(res.body).be.a('Array');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Why did you split that over two tests, then? That's one test, with multiple steps.

Comment: Because I have all of my tests, based on the type of request:POST,GET,PUT,DELETE, grouped together, within different 'descirbes'. Would joining them together, be the only way solve this issue?

Comment: Are you running your tests with the flag `--parallel` or `-p`? check your npm task for the mocha command, without that mocha should run your test in the order you write it..

Comment: Here's how I Do it :`xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:3000/myPostApi", false);      // false === synchronous/blocking`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do all into 'POST' test.

I use this method for test the post API:

```
//Pseudocode
request(app)
  .post()
  .expect().then({
    //do assertions
    request(app)
      .get()
      .expect().then({
        //do assertions
      })
  })
```

I understand that you have to get every test dividied into its suite, but this is not a 'GET test' into 'POST suite'. This is a POST test where you use GET API to assert the data has been inserted. So is completly a 'POST test'.

So, the code will be something like that (I like to use done()):

```js
it('should post', (done) => {
    request(app)
        .post('/endpoint')
        .expect(200).then(postResponse => {
            //assertion
            request(app)
                .get('/endpoint')
                .expect(200).then(getResponse => {
                    //assertion
                    done()
                }).catch(e => {
                    done(e)
                })
        }).catch(e => {
            done(e)
        })
})
```